# How to automatically remove HTML comments in Release mode?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, comments, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to find a way to automatically remove HTML comments in release mode for two main reasons

- Minification: there is a lot of comments in some pages
- Comments contain development notices and TODO lists (which are exposed to end user).

I am using ASP.NET MVC and looking for something in the same spirit as the bundling and minification features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Razor server side comments](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)

```
@*
This is a server side 
multiline comment 
*@
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with build scripts that is what I would recommend. I also use build scripts for deployment, web.config modification, creating backups etc...

Check this link. It explains how to modify a xml file during build:
http://www.federicosilva.net/2013/02/msbuild-in-line-task-to-modify-file.html

You can also write an own task quite easily.

```
public class HtmlSanitizingTask : ITask
{
    [Required]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public bool Execute()
    {
        //ToDo: Implement HTML Sanitizing here
        return true;
    }

    public IBuildEngine BuildEngine { get; set; }
    public ITaskHost HostObject { get; set; }
}
```

Build it and reference the DLL from a build script.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyNamespace.HtmlSanitizingTask" AssemblyName="MyNamespace.dll" />
```

And then call the operation

```
<MyNamespace.HtmlSanitizingTask FilePath="filepathHere" />
```

I hope it helps :)